# swapping 2 nodes in a linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to swap 2 adjacent nodes in a linked list (75 and 9 in this case), and every time I run the code, say with a linked list of 75->9->767->2..., I get the whole list just turning to 75->9->75->9->75->9, etc.. I have to update pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for pairwise swap, use this for the same. Let me know if it went fine. 
for 75->9->767->2 it produces 9->75->2->762... If you want something different but similar, you can use it and make changes accordingly.
    void swap(struct node **head)
    {
        if (*head == NULL || (*head)->next == NULL)
            return;

```
    struct node *prev = *head;
    struct node *cur = (*head)->next;

    *head = cur;  

    while (true)
    {
        struct node *next = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev; 

        if (next == NULL || next->next == NULL)
        {
            prev->next = next;
            break;
        }

        prev->next = next->next;

        prev = next;
        cur = prev->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a bubble-sort and my main problem is currently with bad access as I don't know how to set a suitable while condition to terminate the loop, seeing as we have 3 pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the lines

`nextPtr->next = tempPtr;`
`nextPtr = tempPtr;`

I'm not sure, but i think you only mean to type

`nextPtr = tempPtr;`

instead.

Comment: Ok, there's an improvement, but hdList doesn't actually ever swap anything. When it gets to hdList =  nextPtr, it points to it's next element, but then when it gets to nextPtr = tempPtr, it doesn't actually update hdList's next element to become what I wanted to swap with, so from 75->9->767->, I get 9->767 (i.e  hdList = nextPtr), but how do I get 75 back to be the next element on the list. When I type in hdList->next = nextPtr after nextPtr = tempPtr, I get 9->75->9->75->9->75....infinitely

Comment: since you are moving nextptr to hdlist, you then have to make sure that the new hdlist points to the old hdList->next.

Comment: Isn't that what hdList = nextPtr does?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you want to swap nodes H (what you're calling hdList) and N (nextPtr) in a linked list you have to make whatever points to H now point to N. You're not keeping track of whatever points to H at all.

That is, suppose you know that part of your list is

```
...   P -> H -> N -> Q ...
```

and you want to swap H and N. The state of the list after the swap should be

```
...  P -> N -> H -> Q ...
```

right? But you can't do this because you don't know what used to point to H (i.e. P) so you can make it point to N.

I think you're going to have to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: So I've followed your suggestions, and I get the elements swapping, but I get a bad access because I need to increment the pointers forward each loop and

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap 2 nodes in linked list, why are you trying to swap the pointers and all? Just swap the data in it with the simple swap logic. let the pointers be as it is. If this is not what you want, tell me in detail what exactly you want it to be.

Comment: Part of the question states that we shouldn't swap data :(